# Javascript object value returning undefined with string key

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to update the class of an element based on the properties of some other element. I am able to correctly get the required value, for instance

alignment = "start"

But when I try to get its associated value from the object, it returns undefined, what might be the possible reasons for that. Also ,is there a better way to achieve this.

```
//Update Alignment Button
    var alignmentMap = {
        "end": "bi-text-right",
        "start": "bi-text-left",
        "center": "bi-text-center",
        "justify": "bi-justify"
    }
    var alignment = $(activeId+" .component-content").css("text-align");
    console.log(alignmentMap[alignment]);
    alignment = alignmentMap[alignment];
    $("#cp-align .settings-container i").attr("class", "bi "+alignment);
```

Comment: FYI `alignmentMap` isn't an array. It's an object. You can access properties of an object using dot notation or bracket notation. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: @jarmod I have tried that, but it is returning undefined. Now, either it is a issue because of some stack thing or maybe the order in which things are happening, I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the value of `alignment`? The docs say that jquery css() returns one or more style properties. Is it a string or is it an array? Believe it's a string because you're passing a single property name. What's the value?

Comment: string it is...

Comment: @consolenine What's the *type* and *value*  of `alignment`. Add a `console.log(\`${typeof alignment}  --${alignment}--\`)` to see its type and value and then check if your object has a property with that value ... The output should be something like `string --start--`. If `alignmentMap[alignment]` returns undefined, then there isn't a property with that value ...

Comment: I tested the code in a different page with just the required elements, and it seems to be working fine. I think the issue might be because of something else in my code.

Comment: @derpirscher I believe you should do `console.log(typeof alignment, alignment)` instead for better logging. Otherwise you only get the stringified output of the value, which may be unhelpful (e.g. `"[object Object]"` for objects).

Comment: @OskarGrosser If it outputs something different from `string` at `typeof alignment` the actual value of alignment is irrelevant anyways because anything other than a string cannot be used to access the properties of the object ... And if alignment really is a string, it will output the correct value.

Comment: @OskarGrosser  And the `--${alignment}--` is just to rule out there is some leading or trailing whitespace (unlikely, in the current situation, but it might happen somewhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available text-align property in CSS are `left`, `right`, `center`, `justify`. If the text-align CSS property is set to `text-alight: left`, then the `alignment` value should be `left` and corresponding key in the `alignmentMap` object should be `left`, not start. Same for `right` as well.

```
//Update Alignment Button
var alignmentMap = {
    "right": "bi-text-right",
    "left": "bi-text-left",
    "center": "bi-text-center",
    "justify": "bi-justify"
}
var alignment = $(activeId+" .component-content").css("text-align");
console.log(alignmentMap[alignment]);
alignment = alignmentMap[alignment];
$("#cp-align .settings-container i").attr("class", "bi "+alignment);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. Such a trivial thing, yet I was looking for other issues.